# What type of singularity is $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

Find the residue of $\frac {\cot(z)\coth(z)}{z^3}$ at $z=0$.

In my notebook, i expanded the functions and took the coefficient of $1/z$ as residue, which is $-7/45$

I couldn't recall what type of singularity is this, why we have to take coefficient of $1/z$.

Can you please tell me what type of singularity is this and why we take coefficient of $1/z$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Read  MathJax tutorial so you can typeset the question properly, and include the work you claim you have in your notebook. And check your book for the definition of residue, that might help you.

Comment: Around $0$, $\cot$ and $\coth$ both behave like $1/z$, hence you have a pole of order $5$.

Comment: "Why we take the coefficient of $1/z$ ... when we integrate $\int z^k \,dz$ around the unit circle, we get zero *except* when $k=-1$.  So  the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is the important one.

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align*}\cot(z)\coth(z)&=\frac{\cos(z)\cosh(z)}{\sin(z)\sinh(z)}\\&=\frac{\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)}{\left(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)\left(z+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}\\&=\frac{1-\frac{z^4}6+\cdots}{z^2-\frac{z^6}{90}+\cdots}\end{align*}In the numerator, all the exponents are multiples of $4$ and in the denomitor they are all of the type $4n-2$. So, this quotient can be written as $\frac{a_0+a_1z^4+a_2z^8+\cdots}{z^2}$. It is easy to see that $a_0=1$ and that $a_1=-\frac7{45}$. So$$\frac{\cot(z)\coth(z)}{z^5}=\frac1{z^5}-\frac7{45z}+\cdots$$and the residue is equal to $-\frac7{45}$. Furtermore, this singularity is a pole.